# Strange behavior of a property within root app

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app with 3 components and the root component `AppComponent`.

With the root html component `app.component.html` I use angular 2 material and I have

```
<md-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="loading"></md-progress-bar>
```

With `app.component.ts`

```
loading: boolean = true;
```

So when one component going to be loaded, progress bar is showing.

My first component: `AnalyticsDataComponent` works perfect and looks like:

```
   loading;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.auth.redirectNotAuthUser();
this.getData();
    }


        getData() {
            this.loading = true;
            this.ready = false;
            this.services.getData(this.cookie.get(), this.startDate, this.endDate)
                .subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    this.analyticsData = []; // clean previus data from object
                    this.overall = response.overall;
                    response.data.forEach((element: any, index: number) => {
                        this.analyticsData.push(
                            new AnalyticsData({
                                pagePath: element.pagePath,
                                pageTitle: element.pageTitle,
                                wholeProfit: element.wholeProfit,
                                uniquePageView: element.uniquePageView,
                                entrance: element.entrance,
                                avgTime: element.avgTime,
                                bounceRate: element.bounceRate,
                                pageView: element.pageView,
                                author: element.author
                            })
                        );
                    });
                    this.ready = true;
                    this.whileLoding = true;
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.whileLoding = true;
                    console.log('Error happened' + error);
                },
                () => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.shareService.analyticsData = this.analyticsData;
                    this.shareService.overallData = this.overall;
                    console.log('the subscription is completed');
                }
                );
        }
```

My second component: `TeamIncomeComponent` also works perfect and looks like:

```
  loading;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.redirectNotAuthUser();
    this.getTeamIncomeReport();
  }

  getTeamIncomeReport() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.service.get().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.team = data.team;
        this.users = this.sort.object(data.users);
        this.months = data.months;
      },
      (error) => { },
      () => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.isReady = true;
      }
    );
  }
```

The problem is with third component: `AdvertCommissionComponent`:

```
    loading;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.redirectNotAuthUser();
    this.getCommissions();
  }

  getCommissions() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.service.get().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.advertCommission = data;
      },
      (error) => { },
      () => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.isReady = true;

      }
    );
  }
```

After the request is done the progress bar still appear. Is like that the `AdvertCommissionComponent` does not have access to the `loading` property.

Comment: It isn't clear how these components are connected. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary. Please, provide a plunk that can show this behaviour.

Comment: components typically have their own templates, which are rendered and modeled within the component. Also `loading` variable defined in app.component willnot be accessible by other components.Try using services.